# Neo4j : Traversal Framework in C#

Tags: c#, neo4j, graph-traversal

Can I use Traversal framework of Neo4j in C# ? 
If I can, then which package is to be downloaded from Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: The traversal framework is Java only and usable only when running on the same machine as the Neo4j instance. This means it's available when using embedded Neo4j, or when you're creating a kernel extension or a stored procedure (both of which execute within the same JVM as a running Neo4j server).